# Display array in vuetify data table which not containe tr or td

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**my value is in array.which contains title and description.how can i display only title using dataTable?**

[header code in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmtTT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify `v-data-table` renders column for each item in `headers` array. If you don't want to see a column for some object property, do not include header definition for it in `headers` prop...